# How to write a (first-order) derivative as a function in R?

Tags: r, function, derivative

I need the derivative of p-t*(p^g)*(1-p)^d) as a function of p. 
t,d and g are all defined.
I was trying:

```
firstder<-D(expression(p-t*(p^g)*(1-p)^d), "p")
firstderivative<-function(p){
firstder
}
```

However, calling

```
firstderivative(p=0.1)
```

gives me nothing more than the expression of the first derivative. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstder` is an object of class `"call"`.

```
class(firstder)
#[1] "call"
```

You are forgetting to evaluate the call.

```
firstder <- D(expression(p-t*(p^g)*(1-p)^d), "p")

firstderivative <- function(p){
    eval(firstder)
}

g <- 1
d <- 1
t <- 1
firstderivative(p=0.1)
#[1] 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy using `mosaicCore` package. Given that you have `F(x)=x^2` and you wish to calculate the derivative  based on `x` so you have:

```
library(mosaicCore)


dx2x <- deriv(~ x^2, "x") 
x <- -1:2
eval(dx2x)
```

In your case, it would be:

```
library(mosaicCore)

dx <- deriv(~expression(p-t*(p^g)*(1-p)^d), "p")

x <- -1:2
eval(dx)
```